# What else should use I along with VS 2008 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've just installed VS2008 Express Edition. I'm still reading the "What's new" section.

I just wanted to know from *your* personal experience what else you would recommend I use.

For example: VS2008 SDK, Silverlight, WPI or anything else to make my applications/utilities more pleasant & user friendly.

I'm also having a doubt:

Do all uitlities developed in VS2008 EE require Framework V3.5 on  the client machine? Or is it possible that those utilities will work perfectly the 3.0 framework?
Or can I control the usage of framework versions by my utilities

Friends, Let ur expeirence speak for me.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific.  As it is written, you would need several pages to answer it properly.

Comment: Hey Robert, I had been working in VS2005 till now, switching to 2008 raised lots of questions in my head. I had asked that Q to know if experienced people here can let me know if I should install something right now so that I can unlock VS2008 in best way. I'm now converting my previous projects in 2008, can u let me know what I should keep in mind while working in 2008? Any great feature u can tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question turned to be a question about a plan for learning programming, which is a very very long plan. I will give you here the **beginning tips** from my personal view:

1- Learning how to use the IDE (Visual Studio) is not the **main** issue, learning the language (C#) and the technology (.NET) is **more** important.

2- More important than learning a programming language, is learning **How to program?**, that is: you should learn Algorithms, data structures, software engineering, database design, ...etc. besides learning the programming language.

3- If you are a beginner, VS Express will fulfill most of your needs, as you upgrade your skills, you will find it has some limitations. You can find a comparison between different Visual Studio Editions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz%28VS.80%29.aspx).

4- Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is the new Microsoft's way for building **Cool** Desktop applications, but you still need the traditional WinForms.

5- The world is going **Web**, then you have to check the ASP.NET paths (ASP.NET, ASP.NET Ajax, ASP.NET MVC). The Web counterpart of WPF is SilverLight (which was formerly a part of the WPF itself).

6- As per [VS Express FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx):

> The ability to target a version of the
>   .NET Framework other than 3.5 (i.e.
>   multi-targeting) is included in all
>   the Visual Studio Express Edition
>   products. Multi-targeting is available
>   under the Project Properties menu
>   which can be selected by going to
>   Project->  Properties.

Comment: I'm a newbie only, I still need to learn C# in a better way. Instead of just downloading C# ebooks, I felt its better to install VS and then start reading.... while I code. Hope I'll get a nice tutorial to start on. Any more suggestions please? :)

Comment: @gsvirdi:If you want to learn "How to program?" then consider what I have said above. If you need a good tutorial about C# and .NET, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx and as you said: programming = practice.

Answer (score 1):

When using Visual Studio (including express edition) you can change the target environment of your project to different versions of .NET, though this will limit your application to the features available from that version.

To do this, open the properties of your project, select the 'Application Tab', and change 'Target Environment' to your version of choice.

Comment: Thx Andrew for that Tip, the prob is that other computers in the network are still using framework v3.0 so u c I was a bit worried about the use of my newly developed test utilities on 2008. :)